# Does AWS Elastic Cache support Pub/Sub on Redis Cluster?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, redis, amazon-elasticache, node-xmpp

Looking the documentation of AWS Elastic Cache I can see they support Redis Cluster and talk about key/value data and Redis operations in general.
However is not clear for me if this will support replication of Redis' pub/sub along the different servers.

We are building a chat server on node-xmpp. We will have many application servers for handling chat connections and we are relying on Redis pub/sub for handling the communication between chat threads. We require that regardless the actual Redis instance each chat server is communicating to, they can share the same pub/sub channel.

At [AWS Elastic cache white paper (page 7)](https://d0.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/performance-at-scale-with-amazon-elasticache.pdf)  they indicate to use Redis if you want pub/sub. I understand from this that AWS Elastic Cache will actual support pub/sub scalability but I'm not convinced yet.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have tried it and yes, AWS manages pub/sub channels among Redis instances within a cluster. We have deployed now three chat platforms using node-xmpp and redis-cluster on AWS Elastic Cache for managing the real-time capabilities of the chat, and it works neatly.